# How to configure bazel to run address / memory sanitizer?

Tags: c++, bazel, address-sanitizer

I have project in bazel with very simple bulid rule

```
cc_binary(
  name = "search",
  srcs = [
    "iterator_range.h",
    "main.cpp",
    "parse.cpp",
    "parse.h",
    "search_server.cpp",
    "search_server.h",
    "test_runner.h",
    "profile.h",
  ]
)
```

And I'm getting `Segmentation fault 11`

I've tried to use [this configuration](https://github.com/bazelment/trunk/blob/master/tools/bazel.rc) but got error

```
every rule of type cc_binary implicitly depends upon the target '//tools/lrte:toolchain', but this target coul
d not be found because of: no such package 'tools/lrte': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories
```

Answer (score 9):

I tried to add the `BUILD` file at `tools/lrte` but it resulted in more errros like `no such attribute 'dynamic_runtime_libs' in 'cc_toolchain' rule`.

[The documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html) says:

> By default, Bazel automatically configures CcToolchainConfigInfo for your build, but you have the option to configure it manually

Since I don't want to do toolchain configuration manually (I think) I tried to remove `build:asan --crosstool_top //tools/lrte:toolchain` line from `.bazelrc`. Then I also had to delete the second line about compiler and it worked. So my final `.bazelrc` (`.bazelrc` should be in the same dir `WORKSPACE` is) configuration looks like this:

```
build:asan --strip=never
build:asan --copt -fsanitize=address
build:asan --copt -DADDRESS_SANITIZER
build:asan --copt -O1
build:asan --copt -g
build:asan --copt -fno-omit-frame-pointer
build:asan --linkopt -fsanitize=address
```

Way to run bazel with address sanitizer:

```
bazel build -c dbg --config=asan path/to/module:target
bazel run -c dbg --config=asan path/to/module:target
```

Comment: Worked great on the first try!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without dumping the cache?